# Monitor will not sleep when/after using remote desktop

Tags: windows-vista, display, remote-desktop, power-management

After I remote into my desktop machine the monitor will not sleep again until I use the desktop locally. This started several months ago. Hard to say what changed since I don't think I immediately noticed a problem.

When I first remote in the monitor will immediately wake up and display the "remote logged in from blah blah" and will go black after the configured sleep time, but is still powered on.

This is on an nvidia card and Vista SP1, though it started pre-SP1 and I've gone through a few video driver updates by now.

Comment: Why don't you just turn the monitor off when you leave the computer?

Comment: Yes, that's my current solution. Additionally, I'd like the hardware to behave correctly. :)

Comment: I've noticed this too, and I'm using an ATI card, so it's not the video drivers fault. Another things that happens is that maximized windows are displayed behind the task bar, and I have to restart explorer.exe to get maximized windows to "dock" with the taskbar again.

Comment: An update...
I bought a new primary monitor, making the "problem" monitor a second monitor, and the problem went away. Both monitors remain asleep during and after remote desktop sessions.

Comment: Please add an answer to your own question with the info from your last comment, and accept it, so the question does not come up as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original poster discovered a fix for this issue by adding a new monitor to the system.  The new monitor was configured as the primary display, and the "problem" monitor as the secondary.

This indicates the problem was due to some corruption in the display preferences or monitor settings that got reset when the new monitor was added and/or when the displays were reconfigured.

Possible workarounds for the issue:

- some registry hacking in the right place could reset the corrupted settings.  (what's the right place?)
- deleting the problem monitor's device entry from Device Manager and rebooting might force Windows to reset the corrupted settings.

Comment: posted as community wiki so that others can add to or correct this post.  a lot of this is speculation; the "answer" was given by the original poster in comments.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue on my machine by deleting the monitor from Device Manager and restarting.